# xslt text filter for subset of certain node

Tags: xslt

Suppose the following xhtml

```
...
  <a>
     skipcontent_1
     <div>
        skipcontent_2
     </div>
     <div id='info'>
       showcontent_3
       <div>
         showcontent_4
       </div>
       <c>
         skipcontent_5
       </c>
     </div>
  </a>
...
```

I would like to have only the text from those `div` elements, which have `id='info'` or are below of such a div

So the result should look like this

```
       showcontent_3
         showcontent_4
```

(ident/newlines are not important)

I tried hard to have an identity transformation acting like this, but already failed by letting it ignore the nodes/content "outside" of a `<div id='info'/>` section...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like your problem is a better fit for a stylesheet without an identity template. This stylesheet satisfies your requirements given that input:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="text()" priority="1">
        <!-- Do not output text normally -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div/text()[ancestor::div[@id = 'info']]" priority="2">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To deconstruct a bit:

1. Generally, you want to output nothing. That's the reason for the first template, since default behavior in XSLT for a text node is to copy it to output.
2. You *do* want certain text nodes to be copied to output, so the second template handles those. The match expression finds text nodes that satisfy two things: (1) that they are a text node that is a child of a `div` element (`div/text()`) and (2) that they are somewhere beneath a `div` element that has the `@id` attribute set to "info" (`[ancestor::div[@id = 'info']]`).

(The second template's match expression could be (more or less) equivalently written as `div[@id = 'info']//text()[parent::div]`.)

Comment: What is the purpose of the priority attribute?

Comment: Because a given text node could potentially match either of these templates, the XSLT processor needs to choose which template to invoke. By using the `priority` attribute, we can control the exact order in which the processor attempts to find a match. (There is [a process by which the processor will assign a priority to a template](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#conflict) even if the `priority` attribute is not given, but it's generally considered a best practice to assign your own priority values.)